# prestodb vs prestosql insert-existing-partitions-behavior

Tags: presto, trino

the config below exists in prestosql(trino) but not in prestodb. How can we get same functionality using prestodb ?

```
"hive.insert-existing-partitions-behavior"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the functionality exists in Trino ([and there's a lot more features](https://trino.io/blog/2021/01/08/2020-review.html) than [just this](https://trino.io/blog/2020/01/01/2019-summary.html)) then why not switch to Trino?

The answer to your question is wait for Presto to cherry pick it from Trino. Depending on [how much the projects have diverged](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html) in this particular segment of the code or lack of interest for Facebook to pick it up, you may be waiting for quite some time.

Comment: Well you are right, but switching to other product takes time/decisions/resources etc.  For people who are interested in answer, we noticed an inconsistency with partitioned table insert, we solved our issue other way around, still could not find solution.